# Telerik RadGridView events after data is bound

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I am using telerik library 2011.3.1220.40 in a Windows forms application. My purpose is to add data to a new column based on the data that is already loaded and bound to the view. Is there an event that is triggered after the data is bound? And I don't know why I cannot have access to Rows collection in such example: myGrid.Rows[3]

Comment: Can you please post some code of your setup. Also, what columns do you have, are the auto generated or you are adding them, what is the new column you add and how you would calculate its value?

Comment: Actually I am working on a project of the company I m working with and there is no possibility of copy/pastr the code, however, the columns are not auto generated they are created in such way: <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PropertyFomModel, Mode=OneWay}" Header="ColumnName" /> in the view .xaml file, and the data is bound from the Model in the code behind . The column i want to add is created in the same way in the view except that the data i want must be calculated depending on the values of the other columns not from the Model.

Comment: Have you tried `DataBindingComplete` event for `RadGridView` control? This is fired after your grid view is data bound.

Comment: This event is not provided by telerik for WPF

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using RadGridView for WPF, not WinForms. Here is an article regarding expression columns in Telerik UI for WPF: [link](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/expression-column)